# Qt: How to set header on child tables in QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: qt

QAbstractItemModel has a setHeaderData( int section, ..... ) method that takes a section which is either a row or a column depending on the header orientation. I have a model that contains several tables which are all children of the top item. That is, the first level of my model hierarchy (under the invisible root) consists of 8 rows, each row has a child element which is a table (8 tables total of course). It appears setHeaderData will provide views with a header for the first level, but how do I specify header data for these child tables? QTableView has a setRootIndex() method so it can drill down into the model hierarchy and display the data in these child tables, and I would expect setHeaderData to also take a root index, but it doesn't.  I can set the header manually on the QTableView, but that's a lot messier--is there a better solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, model API doesn't provide a good way to do this. The simplest solution is to make your model return different `headerData` depending on root index currently in use. However, this means that the model needs to know view's state (more specifically, the root index), which is not what you usually want.

I think setting a proxy model could be an elegant solution to this problem. Here is how it can be implemented:

```
class ChildHeadersProxy : public QSortFilterProxyModel {
public:
  static const int HorizontalHeaderRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;
  static const int VerticalHeaderRole = Qt::UserRole + 2;

  void setRootIndex(const QModelIndex& index) {
    m_rootIndex = index;
    if (sourceModel()) {
      emit headerDataChanged(Qt::Horizontal, 0, sourceModel()->columnCount(m_rootIndex));
      emit headerDataChanged(Qt::Vertical, 0, sourceModel()->rowCount(m_rootIndex));
    }
  }

  QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, 
                      int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
    if (sourceModel() && m_rootIndex.isValid()) {
      int role = orientation == Qt::Horizontal ? HorizontalHeaderRole : VerticalHeaderRole;
      QStringList headers = sourceModel()->data(m_rootIndex, role).toStringList();
      if (section >= 0 && section < headers.count()) {
        return headers[section];
      }
    }
    return QSortFilterProxyModel::headerData(section, orientation, role);
  }

private:
  QModelIndex m_rootIndex;

};
```

This proxy model uses headers provided by the source model through two custom roles. For example, if you use `QStandardItemModel`, setting headers is as simple as this:

```
model.item(0, 1)->setData(QStringList() << "h1" << "h2", 
  ChildHeadersProxy::HorizontalHeaderRole);
model.item(0, 1)->setData(QStringList() << "vh1" << "vh2", 
  ChildHeadersProxy::VerticalHeaderRole);
```

where `model.item(0, 1)` is corresponding root item. Setting the view will look like:

```
QTableView view;
ChildHeadersProxy proxy;
proxy.setSourceModel(&model);
view.setModel(&proxy);
```

And changing the root index will look like:

```
view.setRootIndex(proxy.mapFromSource(model.index(0, 1)));
proxy.setRootIndex(model.index(0, 1));
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but your solution looks good--very flexible. I think for my application, since the model is very rigid, it'll be simpler to just return a separate header model for the table views. Thanks, though.